# Matching multiple pseudo classes

Tags: css

I want to know is there a way to doing something like this in CSS:

```
.menu a:match(:active:hover:visited)
{ }
```

instead of

```
.menu a, .menu a:active, .menu a:hover, .menu a:visited
{ }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `.menu a, .menu a:active, .menu a:hover, .menu a:visited` ?

Comment: Nothing, its working but i wonder is there a better way.

Comment: if it ain't broke don't fix it!

Comment: There isn't a way... yet - what you want to do is (will be some day) in [css4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches).

Answer (score 1):

If your `a` have same `color` for all states so, it's better write like this:

```
.menu a{
 color:red;
}
```

instead of

```
.menu a, .menu a:active, .menu a:hover, .menu a:visited{color:red}
```

Comment: I'm already have that but the page has common class for all "a" tags so the a tags which is in the .menu elements is matching that common class's :visited and :hover pseudos. I wish i could write understandable my problem.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is currently no mechanism to do what you want. You need to list all the selectors in full, as per what you are trying to avoid:

```
.menu a, .menu a:active, .menu a:hover, .menu a:visited
```

CSS is currently more like a markup language than a programming language. As Litek notes in the comments, however, `:matches:()` [proposed for CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) does exactly what you described (and more).